# While using ag-grid dataSurce, how can I know if the getRows function being called due to scrolling or filtering

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

As we know, in `infinite` `rowModelType`, we have to set `dataSource` for the [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid).

```
const dataSource = {
  rowCount: count
  getRows: (params: IGetRowsParams) => this.getRows(params, [])
};
this.gridApi.setDatasource(dataSource);
```

Now, `dataSource.getRows` method is called whenever there is need to fetch the rows in the grid (due to scrolling) ***OR*** the filter is changed.

I need to decide how many ajax calls need to be made depending on this reason. Below code blocks explains this.

```
private getRows(params: IGetRowsParams, data: any) {
    // two ajax calls can be made from here
    // 1. getCount
    // 2. getData

    //  if this getRows function is called due to scrolling in the grid,
    //     I just want to call getData - no need to call getCount as I already know it
    //  if this is called due to change in filter,
    //     I need to call getCount as well as the no of rows will be different

    // How can I know here due to which above mentioned reasons, getRows is getting called?
}
```

Is there anyway to know it within `getRows` function?

Comment: the feature is there in https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/. AG-2001: Add source to the IServerSideGetRowsParams